# OnListItemClick to open a new Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm using "Action bar Sherlock" and "SlidingMenu" libraries.
I have a List of 5 items, I want to change fragments on clicking an item from the list.
Here's my code so far, I'm trying to use OnListItemClick but I don't really know how to use it.

```
public class RandomList extends SherlockListFragment {

    String[] list_contents = {"Page 1", "Page 2", "Page 3", "Page 4", "Page 5" };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_contents));
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        // **Open different fragment after click**
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one of your [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) (let's call it MyFragment) correlates to the first item in your SlidingMenu:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public static Fragment newInstance(...) {
        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
        // Since fragments require that you have a
        // public constructor with zero arguments, then
        // we use this pattern to initialize the fragment.
        ...
        return f;
    }
    ...
}
```

You can use a switch statement:

```
void callFragmentFromDrawer(int position) {
    Fragment f = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            f = MyFragment.newInstance();
            break;
        case 1:
        ...
    }

    if (f != null) {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, f)
            .addToBackStack(list_contents[position])
            .commit();
    }
}
```

Then,

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    callFragmentFromDrawer(position);
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much how the author of SlidingMenu did it in the demo app, though your solution is actually a little cleaner. I think it needs a getActivity() and a cast there though to get the FM though.

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot we were in a ListFragment :-P Updated to reflect that fact by calling getActivity() before getSupportFragmentManager().

Comment: Sorry, where is MyFragment coming from in this line

f = MyFragment.newInstance();

Thanks!

Comment: The pattern is called a "static factory method" from the book [Effective Java](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-2nd-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683/). I've updated the answer to include an example of its use. You can also find the example at the bottom of the [Fragments Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)